# Constrain Values per Overlying Group

Tags: postgresql, supabase

- Each `organisation` has a unique name.
- Within each `organisation` can be multiple `teams`, whose names should be unique, but only within their own `organisation`.
- Also, each `team` can have `projects`, which names again should be unique per `team`.

Overall, expect for the `organisation`, names should be unique per their own "group", but can be duplicates otherwise.

I think I would need to create a constraint that CHECKs whether a given name already exists in the "overlying group", but I struggle to do this with the complex SQL (exclusion) constraints.

Would it be possible to write such a constraint ?

Comment: Can't you just have a unique index on organization and team?  That would guarantee that no team name is duplicated within an organization.  Same thing for team and project, just use a unique index.

Comment: If each entity is stored in separate table, and according relations are set, then UNIQUE constraints solves.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming this is for PostgreSQL based on the two other tags (Postgresql & Supabase).

You can do this directly in the primary keys. Here's how the bare bones of such a structure would look like:

```
CREATE TABLE organization (
   org_name text  NOT NULL,
   PRIMARY KEY (org_name)
);

CREATE TABLE teams (
   org_name text NOT NULL,
   team_name text NOT NULL,
   PRIMARY KEY (org_name, team_name),
   FOREIGN KEY (org_name)
      REFERENCES organization (org_name)
);

CREATE TABLE projects (
   org_name text NOT NULL,
   team_name text NOT NULL,
   project_name text NOT NULL,
   PRIMARY KEY (org_name, team_name, project_name),
   FOREIGN KEY (org_name)
      REFERENCES organization (org_name),
   FOREIGN KEY (org_name, team_name)
      REFERENCES teams (org_name, team_name)
);
```

Notes, this will allow things like `ORg Contoso` & `Org CONTOSO` you may want to pick [citext](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/citext.html) instead of text as the type to avoid such names.

Comment: That's quite clever! Just by defining the primary keys as a composite of its own and the foreign table IDs it doesn't even need any complex constraints to be duplicate-free in that namespace.

Comment: One more thing: Anything to look out for when  renaming items?