# supabase: error: duplicate key value violates unique constraint "cartItems_pkey1"

Tags: database, next.js, deployment, supabase, supabase-database

I save data on my database with an RLS feature for authenticated users who can only insert, update, and delete their data; this works well.
When I save data on the database, I check if any data with that id exist; if it does,increase the quantity if it doesn't create on the database. This works great; however, if an authenticated user saves an item with an id on the database, another user cannot save the same data with the id on the database because it looks like a duplicate even though this is from another user. How can I combat this please?

```
      if(user){
          console.log(user)
          //check if the object exists already on our database using the ID
          const { data, error } = await supabaseClient
            .from('cartItems')
            .select()
            .eq('id', uniqueId)

            console.log('product widget', data)
  
            if (data.length > 0) {
              // if data exists get its quantity and add it to new quantity
              const newQuantity = data[0].quantity + counter
  
              //update the cart item on the database
  
              const { error } = await supabaseClient
                .from('cartItems')
                .update({ quantity: newQuantity })
                .eq('id', uniqueId)
  
                if (error) {
                  // console any error we encounter along the way
                  console.log(error)
                  alert('Error adding the item to your wishlist')
                } else {
                  // alert that we have added to our wishlist successfully
    
                  alert('item added successfully to wishlist')
                }
  
            } else {
              // add a new item if the item is not available on our database
              const { error } = await supabaseClient
                .from('cartItems')
                .insert(
                  {
                    id: uniqueId,
                    name,
                    price,
                    image_src: imageSrc,
                    image_alt: imageAlt,
                    quantity: counter
                  }
                )
  
              if (error) {
                // console any error encountered
  
                console.log(error)
                alert('Error adding the item to your wishlist, 2nd part')
              } else {
                alert('item added to Wishlist')
              }
  
            }
          if(error){
            console.log(error, 'error checking if the cart item data exists already')
          }

        }
```

[image]

Comment: Hey, did you check my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74032182/constrain-values-per-overlying-group/74032909#74032909)? 

Seems like the kind of setup you want to achieve.